# phrasing would your tomorrow around or would around your tomorrow

Tags: grammar

What is the correct order of phrasing the following sentence:
1. Would your tomorrow around 3pm work? 
2. Would around your tomorrow 3pm work?

Comment: _"Would around 3 PM tomorrow work for you?"_

Answer (score 1):

In general you would not say "your tomorrow" (well maybe if they are in a different time zone) since all our tomorrow will be the same date. So you could say:

> Would tomorrow around 3pm work?.

The comment by Lascivious Grace is also correct, just reversing the date and time.

Regarding your example 2, "around" is really about the time, so it should not modify "tomorrow".

Comment: can "around" modify "tomorrow 3pm (tomorrow's time)?"

Comment: I suppose it could, but as soon as you say "around tomorrow" it seems like you mean the day before or the day after. Maybe its just me but it sounds odd.